# How can I generate the calendar for the year Jesus was born in?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I write

```
$this->calendar->generate(1,1)
```

to display a calendar, but it return as  2001, 1

What am I missing?

Comment: What's the date you want to generate?

Comment: Well in theory the calendar shouldn't really support such a thing. From the period of Jesus being borned and now, the calendar got days missing and days added and a lot of stuff which you can't expect a simple calendar extension to be able to handle. Calendars are usually made for present time and rarely have any reason to work before the year 1970 (start of unix time).

Comment: Surely you meant somewhere between "-7" and "-2", then? :) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jesus#cite_note-0

Comment: Gregorian Calendar, Julian Calendar, or other?